# Plotting of natural bond orbitals (NBOs)

Tags: software, visualization-software, orbitals

Which quantum chemistry programs can compute natural bond orbitals (NBOs)? Which visualisation tools can I use subsequently to plot pictures of the NBOs?

Comment: Well, my experimental colleagues are as impatient as ever ;)

Comment: I can put a bounty on this question to draw more attention to it, if needed. It will only let me put a bounty after 2 days though.

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer helps you (you might have already known about that software). I googled it since your experimental colleagues are impatient and I wanted to help solve that, and this is just what I've found (I don't have experience with the program). Your question is posted on twitter: https://twitter.com/StackMatter/status/1273342612867514369 to get more attention, and you can re-tweet it to help raise more awareness.

Comment: is this question about computing NBOs or plotting them? The two are very different.

Comment: I was thinking about the whole workflow from computing to plotting. Actually in the meantime I found one possible solution with Q-Chem+Jmol. It took me a while to figures this out since the filenames are a bit cryptic. So, I think it is worth sharing (which I will do now)

Comment: This is also a relevant link: https://joaquinbarroso.com/2009/09/24/nbo-visualization/

Answer (score 12):

## NBO 7.0

The program [NBO 7.0](https://nbo6.chem.wisc.edu/index.htm) seems to be quite well maintained, with version 7.0.9 released fewer than 30 days ago.

**Advantages**:

- [Has interfaces](https://nbo6.chem.wisc.edu/affil_css.htm) to ADF, DEMON2K, FIREFLY/PC-GAMESS, GAMESS(US), GAUSSIAN, JAGUAR/SCHROEDINGER, MOLCAS, MOLPRO, NWChem, ORCA, PQS, Psi4, QChem, SPARTAN, TeraChem, TURBOMOLE.
- At least 2 new releases were issued already in 2020, and at least 2 new releases issued in 2019, so it seems the developers are still active and constantly maintaining the code.
- It has existed since 2001, so it is well established (probably not too many bugs).
- They have [NBOView](https://nbo6.chem.wisc.edu/v_manual.htm) for plotting and visualizing. There is also a plug-in for [visualization with JMol](https://nbo6.chem.wisc.edu/nbopro_adv.htm)
- They have a detailed [manual](https://nbo6.chem.wisc.edu/nboman.pdf) available online.

**Disadvantages**:

- It doesn't seem to have a presence on GitHub
- It is not free. The latest version [seems to cost](https://charge.wisc.edu/chemistry/order_nbo7.aspx) 100 USD or 30 USD as a plut-in to FIREFLY/PC-GAMESS.
- The interfaces to the software above, don't seem to be very up-to-date. For example the website says the MOLCAS interface is only to NBO3.0, not NBO7.0.
- The website seems old-fashioned.

Answer (score 10):

## ADF

With the Amsterdam Modeling Suite you can calculate (ADF, DFTB) and plot NBOs in the graphical user interface within the same package.

- [Here's an example applied to NMR analysis](https://www.scm.com/doc/Tutorials/ADF/NMR_analysis_with_NLMO_and_NBO.html#nmr-analysis-with-nlmo-and-nbo).
- [Here's one applied to TDDFT UV/VIS, including NTOs and NBOs](https://www.scm.com/doc/Tutorials/Advanced/ADF_insight_tutorial_TDDFT_NBO.html).
- [Here's one on NBO and other analysis / visualization (QTAIM)](https://www.scm.com/doc//Tutorials/ADF/QTAIM.html#benzene-qtaim-charge-analysis-and-nbos)

You are welcome to have a [Free Trial](https://www.scm.com/free-trial)!

Answer (score 9):

## Q-Chem + Jmol

The combination of Q-Chem and Jmol seems to work well (but is not yet well documented).

### Q-Chem

In the Q-Chem input file one has to put

```
$rem
...
nbo    = 1
$end

$nbo
PLOT
$end
```

This calls the NBO program and writes out the information of interest to the files `$QCSCRATCH/FILE.[31-39]`

### NBO

The content of the files written is

- `FILE.31` Basis set information
- `FILE.32` PNAOs in the AO basis
- `FILE.33` NAOs in the AO basis
- `FILE.34` PNHOs in the AO basis
- `FILE.35` NHOs in the AO basis
- `FILE.36` PNBOs in the AO basis
- `FILE.37` NBOs in the AO basis
- `FILE.38` PNLMOs in the AO basis
- `FILE.39` NLMOs in the AO basis

Here, the letter P corresponds to the pre-orthogonal orbitals, which are suggested for visualisation ([WIREs, 2012, 2, 1](https://dx.doi.org/10.1002/wcms.51)).

### Jmol

In Jmol, one can just open the file of interest. In the first instance this may be the pre-NBOs as contained in `FILE.36`.

To automate the plotting of orbitals, one may use the `jmol_MOs.py` wrapper supplied with [TheoDORE](http://theodore-qc.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Are you the developer of TheoDORE, fffelix? I was surprised to see that it works with TeraChem.

Comment: Yes, these TDDFT interfaces are quick :) We wrote the interface for this paper:
http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/c7sc01600j

Answer (score 6):

## Jmol

Jmol is a free, open source viewer of molecular structures useful for students, educators and researchers in chemistry, biochemistry and other fields dealing with molecular structure. It is cross-platform, running on Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux/Unix systems.

- The Jmol application is a standalone Java application that runs on the desktop.
- The JSmol is an object that can be integrated into web pages. It does not require Java, since it runs using just the browser's HTML5 and JavaScript engines..
- The JmolViewer is a development tool kit that can be integrated into other Java applications.

You can download it from [here](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/download/).

Comment: I guess one may add here that the files of interest are called FILE.3[1-9] and that Jmol can open these directly.

Comment: @Felix, as you asked about software, these files you mention may not correspond to other ones likes MOPAC.

Answer (score 3):

## MOPAC

MOPAC (Molecular Orbital PACkage) is a semiempirical quantum chemistry program based on Dewar and Thiel's NDDO approximation.

If you qualify for Academic not-for-profit use, request your password [here](http://openmopac.net/redirect_download_form.html).

Using the keyword *[local](http://openmopac.net/manual/localize.html)*, you can calculate the localized orbitals are also known as Natural Bond Orbitals or NBO.